# Link and brush in Matplotlib/Pandas -- plotting selected points from a plot in another plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, correlation

I'm wondering how could I implement some sort of **'link and brush'** in `Matplotlib/Pandas` or if there is another lib that provides this.

For instance, using the `scatter-plot matrix` from `Pandas` I obtained this graph:

[image]

It can be seen, for example, that there is a relation between some points of `||V||` and `||Rf||`.

I have two other graphs (simple `imshow`) representing `||V||` and `||Rf||`, on the other hand.

What I would like to do now is to select (paint) some points of the `scatter-plot matrix` and show then in the other two plots (painting these points too). As I'm trying to say, this doesn't need to be interactive (if that is possible it would be better, though), but I would like to be able to select some points with strong and weak correlations and show them in the other plots too.

There is a way to do that?

**EDIT**

Following the tip given by @dartdog, I managed to send these data to `glue` using this:

```
def glue_variogram(data, data_size, labels):
    data = numpy.array(data)
    glue_data = Data()

    for i in range(0, data_size):
        d = data[i]
        l = labels[i]
        glue_data.add_component(d, label=l)

    collection = DataCollection([glue_data])

    ga = GlueApplication(collection)
    ga.start()
```

However, I'm not sure how (or even if) I could draw the `scatter-plot matrix` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do what you want with glue" http://www.glueviz.org/en/stable/